# TickTuple does not work

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have a storm topology, in which I have a bolt which reads from database and puts into a kafka queue in a batch. It gets more than 20K rows in about 5secs. But the bolt does not receive the tick tuple. And eventually I receive heap space error. So I have limited the count to 10k to push the messages to kafka queue. And when reading from db is finished, I started to get tick tuple messages.

The spout calculates the next data to fetch from the db and gives it to bolt, table name and time range.

`protected static boolean isTickTuple(Tuple tuple) {
        return tuple.getSourceComponent().equals(Constants.SYSTEM_COMPONENT_ID)
                && tuple.getSourceStreamId().equals(Constants.SYSTEM_TICK_STREAM_ID);
    }`

```
@Override
public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
    Config conf = new Config();
    int tickFrequencyInSeconds = 5;
    conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TICK_TUPLE_FREQ_SECS, tickFrequencyInSeconds);
    return conf;
}`
```

Version of Storm is  0.9.3

Comment: What is your spout implementation? It seems back-pressure is killing the tick tuple management. Do you set some parallelism / task parameters for better handling of the load?

Comment: spout just gives out three fields one is the key, and the date range to be read from the db. the date range is incremented in a loop until the current time is reached.

Answer (score 0):

When you call Submitter.submitTopology, you have to pass topology configuration as one of the arguments.

It's likely that you configured tick tuple frequency somewhere else but didn't put it to conf that will be delivered to topology.

Comment: How do you specify tick tuple frequency in a bolt, I guess we do it using the methods I have given in the question.